# Sml overflow while reading integers from text file into a list

Tags: text, input, overflow, smlnj

I am trying to import a text file in SML/NJ containing integers.
While my method work good for small inputs I get an overflow when trying to import bigger files .

In file the first integer is the number of elements following and it can be up to 2*10^6 and numbers following can be positive integers up to 10^9. Given the fact that these numbers are within Int limits :

Is the stack of the program too small and i get an overflow ? Is there a size limitation in lists in SML/NJ.

My code for reading integers into a list :

```
fun parse file =
    let
        fun next_int input =
        Option.valOf (TextIO.scanStream (Int.scan StringCvt.DEC) input)
        val stream = TextIO.openIn file
        val n = next_int stream
    val _ = TextIO.inputLine stream
        fun scanner 0 acc = acc
          | scanner i acc =
            let
                val d = next_int stream
            in
                scanner (i - 1) (d :: acc)
            end
    in
        (n, rev(scanner n []))
    end
```

And the error i get :

```
uncaught exception Overflow [overflow]
  raised at: Basis/Implementation/num-scan.sml:231.20-231.28
```

Comment: The `Overflow` exception is thrown only for number overflows, not stack overflows. In addition, SML/NJ represents its call stack as a linked list, not as an array, so there's no stack overflow error, just a memory limit error. http://sml-family.org/Basis/general.html#SIG:GENERAL.Overflow:EXN

Comment: My hunch is that you have a number greater than `Int.maxInt` in your file. I suggest you add an exception handler in your `next_int` function and print out the culprit number.

Comment: Also, the exception is thrown in a file called `num-scan.sml`, so it must be the number parsing logic at fault.

Comment: @IonuțG.Stan you were right one of the 10^6 numbers had just a digit more so going up the limit of maxInt . However when running now i get a 

uncaught exception Option
 raised at: Basis/Implementation/option.sml:17.25-17.31

Comment: That's because of your `Option.valOf` call. Presumably, the `Int.scan` call encountered a non-numeric line and returned a `NONE`, to which `Option.valOf` will respond with an `Option` exception: http://sml-family.org/Basis/option.html#SIG:OPTION.valOf:VAL